# Reducing white/empty space on page

Tags: margins, koma-script, best-practices

I'm writing a thesis in Texmaker and use the documentclass "scrreprt".
For designing a page I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,DIV=10,BCOR=12mm,oneside,toc=listof,toc=bibliography]{scrreprt}
```

In a tutorial I learned to use this options to get a good result. 
So far, the page looks nice, however there is too much empty space on the bottom.
I know that the DIV option is setting the optimal number of word per sentence and it avoids that a page hat to many words on it.
However, after writing a few hundred pages for the thesis, I want to use more of the white space of every page and reduce the margin.

What it the best and easiest way to adjust the design of the page?
Using the geometry package will change everything, won't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an uptodate KOMA-Script version you can set option `usegeometry` for the class. Then it is possible to load package `geometry` and change the bottom margin.

```latex
\documentclass[
  %fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,% default
  DIV=10,BCOR=12mm,
  %oneside,% default
  toc=listof,toc=bibliography,
  usegeometry% <- added
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[bottom=3cm]{geometry}% <- added
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{layout}% to show the layout
\begin{document}
\layout
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. That solution looks perfect for my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the DIV number to decrease the margin, e.g.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,DIV=13,BCOR=12mm,oneside,toc=listof,toc=bibliography]{scrreprt}
```

Here an overview from the koma documentation with all possible values:

[image]

Comment: @Sveinung There was no comment when I wrote my answer

Comment: However increasing the DIV number will change more than just the margin on the bottom. I like the margins to the left, to the right and to the top as well as the number of words per sentence.

Comment: @Auk Yes, read the KOMA-script documentations, and you will find that this is done to keep the typography (the type area) correct. KOMA-script do not allow typographically unpleasant type areas. If the bottom margin is too big, you can trim the paper after you have finished the thesis. Chapter 2, page 27 in the manual is mandatory reading